# Union of Cartesian products: $X \times (Y \cup Z)= (X \times Y) \cup(X\times Z)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove or disprove $X \times (Y \cup Z)= (X \times Y) \cup(X\times Z)$ 
for all sets $X$, $Y$, and $Z$? I'm lost on the steps here.

Comment: What are the elements in the left side? What the elements in the right side?

Comment: Usually it is best to think about this element wise!

Comment: I'm confused on how to multiply out the elements fully

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is a simplification problem: find out which elements are in $\;(X \times Y) \cup (X \times Z)\;$ by expanding the definitions and simplifying, then work towards $\;X \times (Y \cup Z)\;$.

So for all $\;x\;$,
\begin{align}
& p \in (X \times Y) \cup (X \times Z) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& p \in X \times Y \;\lor\; p \in X \times Z \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\times\;$, twice, writing $\;p\;$ as $\;(x,y)\;$ for some $\;x,y\;$"} \\
& (x \in X \land y \in Y) \;\lor\; (x \in X \land y \in Z) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: extract common conjunct $\;x \in X\;$ -- the key simplification"} \\
& x \in X \land (y \in Y \lor y \in Z) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& x \in X \land (y \in Y \cup Z) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\times\;$, switching back to $\;p\;$"} \\
& p \in X \times (Y \cup Z) \\
\end{align}
By set extensionality, this proves the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the right side first:
Take $a \in (X \times Y) \cup (X \times Z)$. Then what are the possibilities? $a \in (X \times Y)$ or $a \in (X \times Z)$.

Now there are two cases: suppose $a \in (X \times Y)$. If $a \in X \times Y$, then $a \in X \times (Y \cup Z)$, because the cartesian cross product is defined as $A \times B  = \{(a,b) | a \in A \land b \in B\}$, and uniting $Y$ and $Z$ does not mean that we are losing elements of $Y$. The case for $a \in X \times Z$ is similar (you should do that one). Now we have proven that if $a \in (X \times Y) \cup (X \times Z)$, then $a \in X \times (Y \cup Z)$. This implies that $(X \times Y) \cup (X \times Z) \subseteq X \times (Y \cup Z)$.

To show that the sets are equal, we'll then want to show that $ X \times (Y \cup Z) \subseteq (X \times Y) \cup (X \times Z)$. The reasoning in this case (for the entire left side) is similar to the reasoning above. I'll leave it to you, as this vaguely looks like homework.

Comment: The confusion I have is on the multiplication of the left side, i understand the element phase on the right side you just did. If I'm proving that X x (YvZ) is a subset, then its false correct, since the initial X is not included??

Comment: $X \times (Y \cup Z) = \{(a,b) | a \in X$ and $b \in (Y \cup Z)\}$.

Comment: SO then therefore based off that it's false, since YvZ isnt a subset right?

Comment: No... $(Y \cup Z)$ is just the collection of elements that are in $Y$ and $Z$. If $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{a\}$ and $Z = \{b,c\}$, then $(Y \cup Z) = \{a,b,c\}$ and $X \times (Y \cup Z) = \{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c),(3,a),(3,b),(3,c)\}$.

Comment: So because X is the subset of YvZ that makes it equal because we proved the right side to be a subset of the left already?(and thanks for help also)

Comment: X is not a subset of $(Y \cup Z)$. Please re-read the post carefully. We proved the right side to be a subset of the left side. Then we need to prove that the left side is a subset of the right side. If both sides are subsets of each other, then they must be equal: if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $A=B$.

Comment: Ohhhh. I'ms orry. I think I got it now. So based off the multiplication of X x(Yvz) out, and the right side as well, they are both equal because they are both subsets of each other.( X×Y)∪(X×Z) gives the same products as X×(Y∪Z) if I did my math correctly

Comment: Yes, they are both equal because they are both subsets of each other. We know this because when we select ANY element on the left side, we can show that it is in the right side, and when we select ANY element from the right side, we can show that it is also in the left side. Therefore, both sides are subsets of each other, and therefore, both sides are equal. (Don't think too much about the 'multiplying out'.)

Answer (score 0):

$$A\times(B\cap C)\Leftrightarrow (A\cup A)\times(B\cup C)$$

$\left({x, y}\right) \in \left({A \cup A}\right) \times \left({B \cup C}\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow \left({x \in A \lor x \in A}\right)\land\left({y \in B \lor y \in C}\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow \left[{\left({x \in A \lor x \in A}\right) \land y \in B}\right]\lor\left[{\left({x \in A \lor x \in A}\right) \land y \in C}\right]$

$\Leftrightarrow \left({x \in A \land y \in B}\right)\lor\left({x \in A \land y \in B}\right)\lor\left({x \in A \land y \in C}\right)\lor\left({x \in A \land y \in C}\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow \left({x, y}\right) \in \left({A \times B}\right) \cup \left({A \times B}\right) \cup \left({A \times C}\right) \cup \left({A \times C}\right)$

$\Leftrightarrow \left({x, y}\right) \in \left[\left({A \times B}\right) \cup \left({A \times C}\right)\right]$